# Better way to do a while loop on socket receive?

Tags: java

I have a small java program that listens for lines from a socket and prints them to a JTextArea. Is there a better way to do this:

```
while(true){
 JTextArea.append(in.readLine())
}
```

I was thinking something like an event:

```
event.in.readLine(){
JTextArea.append(in.readLine())
}
```

or is a while loop the best way to do this? Even if I add more functionality to this program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969827/java-networking-evented-socket-inputstream

Comment: In every case you have to delegate the GUI update operation (`JTextArea.append()`) to EDT, otherwise you may experience ugly mulithreading issues

Answer (score 0):

Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to correctly update UI screen and to not block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

None of those.

```
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    textArea.append(line);
}
in.close();
```

This must be on a separate thread from the AWT thread.