# How to check Java Socket InputStream whether it contains data or not before witing data

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I have the below requirement.

A socket based communication where a client socket sends request data in output stream and reads response in input stream. If there is a period of inactivity then server will send two null bytes for every 60 seconds.

I have a code to write and flush request data in output stream followed by reading input stream for response.

1. I sent request-1 and received response-1.
2. Suppose when I send request-2 after two minutes, the response in the input stream is [0,0,0,0] instead of actual response-2. Server has been added these four null bytes as there is 2 minute inactivity.
3. I sent request-3 but received response-2 as it is already available in input stream.

To overcome this issue, I thought of checking input stream whether it contains actual response or null bytes before writing request-2.

Is there any better solution other than inputstream.available() method call.

Comment: How about  using selector on the socket and check for OP_READ key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java networking: evented Socket/InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969827/java-networking-evented-socket-inputstream)

Comment: I don't really understand your protocol and how you match responses to requests. Is the response optional? Are you willing to send new requests before you've receive responses for previous requests? Why not just wait for an actual response before sending a new request?